# Retrofit API call (java) returns empty object

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, wear-os

This is my first application in java. I made an app w ith Ionic/Angular where i am calling this [api](https://new.scoresaber.com/api/player/76561198280372610/basic) and everything works fine.
Now im trying to do the same for smartwatches (Watch OS) and im using Retrofit 2.0 version 2.4.0 with GSON 2.4.0

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```

I didnt really find any tutorials/documentations that helped me with my problem.

This is my code

MainActivity.java:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://new.scoresaber.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

            Call<JSONObject> call = api.getPosts();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
                    //When i debug then the response.body() is just empty
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        JSONObject res = response.body();
                        countryRank.setText(res.toString());
                    }
                    else{
                        countryRank.setText("Response was not successful");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
                    countryRank.setText("error: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

GetRequest.java

```
public class GetRequest {

@SerializedName("playerName")
private String playerName;
private String rank;
private String countryRank;
private String pp;


public String getPlayerName() {
    return playerName;
}

public String getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public String getCountryRank() {
    return countryRank;
}

public String getPp() {
    return pp;
}
}
```

API.java

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface API {

    @GET("api/player/76561198280372610/basic")
    Call<JSONObject> getPosts();

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

n

Comment: And of course i tried postman already, everything worked fine there!

Comment: when you have POJO class why you are using JSONObject

Comment: like i already mentioned, i am new to java and retrofit and dont really know what i am doing yet, can you tell me what i need to change or do different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more POJO for your root object:

```
public class PlayerResponse {
    private GetRequest playerInfo;

    public GetRequest getPlayerInfo() {
        return playerInfo;
    }
}
```

And replace all your `JSONObject`'s with `PlayerResponse`